# TS: ensure an object has a single key of a string union type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to construct a typesafe query system, that looks a bit like MongoDB queries.

I'd like to guarantee an object has a single property of a union type, but don't find a solution. Can someone help me make the following code compile?

```
type Operator = 'AND' | 'OR';

type OperatorNode = { [O in Operator]: [] };

const shouldWork1: OperatorNode = {
  AND: [],
};

const shouldWork2: OperatorNode = {
  OR: [],
};

const shouldFail1: OperatorNode = {};

const shouldFail2: OperatorNode = {
  AND: [],
  OR: [],
};
```

As you can see in the playground, it does not exactly behave the way I want:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYB7eUC8UDkBBAcgCLZQA+OMAStgNwBQdoksCya+KAJtFgN5QBtGFACWAOxYQkqeAF0AXINlQAvvToBjFGIDOwKDoAWKAK4AbTgHU0AawCMiuFLbwO3TFF50oUAoUUCsgA0dGoMWrr6RqYW1vA2AEyOrDJuPJ7esJQBwaHqEXoGxuacAGKIImYOktLsXOm8YZrahdEl5ZVJNS5pHl4+fjkhPlRDeUA

As far as I understand, this may be complicated to achieve due to structural typing, but maybe there are tricks?

Answer (score 6):

The ultimate type you want is this:

```
type OperatorNode = { AND: []; OR?: undefined; } | { OR: []; AND?: undefined; }
```

That is, a union of types, each of which has a single defined property and where the rest of the properties are only allowed to be `undefined` if they are present at all.  You can verify that this works as you intend:

```
const shouldWork1: OperatorNode = { AND: [], }; // okay
const shouldWork2: OperatorNode = { OR: [], }; // okay
const shouldFail1: OperatorNode = {}; // error!
const shouldFail2: OperatorNode = { AND: [], OR: [], }; // error!
```

---

It takes a bit of type juggling to programmatically turn `Operator` into `OperatorNode`.  Here's how I'd go about it:

```
type ExclusiveRecord<K extends PropertyKey, V> = {
  [P in K]: Record<P, V> & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>> extends
  infer O ? { [Q in keyof O]: O[Q] } : never }[K]
```

This uses a few [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to iterate over each element `P` of the union `K` and  constructs `Record<P, V> & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>>`. `Record<P, V>` means it has the `P` key with value `V`, and `Partial<Record<Exclude<K, P>, never>>` means for every key in `K` excluding `P`, it has no defined values.  The bit about `extends infer O...` is just turning that ugly intersection into a single object type so aren't forced to deal with `Record<"AND", []> & Partial<Record<"OR", never>>`.  And then those are all unioned together at the end.  Let's make sure it works:

```
type OperatorNode = ExclusiveRecord<Operator, []>
/* type OperatorNode = {
    AND: [];
    OR?: undefined;
} | {
    OR: [];
    AND?: undefined;
}
*/
```

Yep, looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYB7eUC8UDkBBAcgCLZQA+OMAStgNwBQdokUAogB4DGANgK4DOASwBuEShA5oAJgB4A0lAhtgEAHaS+UAArwUCULIggANFABqAPkxQA3nShQA2pqgCVUWQF0AXFDET4MpomFlAAZFqI8MACiFzSflLS7Nw8khByJprmJioQIvDmlorKanx2LioAZhDoMFAA-DaOAIoVUADWhiiVsN6wDs0eUAC+UD65+SMOngxM0HA1yGj4KGlWybyCIgkB0gtIqPAmDh7mdAD0AFRQc7AIS-Ara1i29vYEhD4n9G+wlPU+HhqCCVVwQST0UbkV5vKhfDw-N4fAFQIFpUG5CF0YZ0S7nBgSFR8YBQPgACxQPC4kgA6mh2gBGHz7B5PaAvKAfeEmYY0KDnc5QFDtRAgOiE4mkilU2n0gBMzPuhzZVmsf25Iz5AqFIrFEpJ5Mp1IAYogBFwmXdFsrVuybLz+YKajp4ABCcUoIkG6Ums1cBVWg7LW2qzlEDVwxweHlap3wF2uoA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks exactly what I was looking for